# Uncrustify configuration for objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uncrustify

I am looking for configurations to use with Uncrustify, for Objective-C.

Searches on google did not return nice configurations for this language.

Comment: i think the reason it has hundreds of parameters is because people's ideas of the best settings differ ;)

Comment: not really an answer, but another way to get happy: reformat the code using AppCode of Jetbrains. The reformatting is much more intuitive

Answer (score 19):

[Here's my Obj-C style](https://gist.github.com/4242629) which i'm constantly tweaking. I try to follow as closely to Apple's style as used in their documentation/WWDC presentations as possible.

I've created an [OS X GUI for uncrustify](https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UncrustifyX) to help you tweak your own style and better document the uncrustify options

Comment: +1 for sharing and being an all-around excellent config. It happens to be almost identical to my own preferred style: my only change was turning off 'nl_create_if_one_liner'. Well done!

Comment: Is there an updated version of your style?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it, so cannot vouch for its beauty, which is after all, in the eye of the beholder. But there's one here:

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/08/07/code-formatting-in-xcode/